# Can the MAC address of a mobile device be easily determined?

Tags: networking, mobile

This is somewhat of a general question, is it realistic to assume that a router can resolve any mobile device's MAC address without being already connected via wifi or bluetooth?

Comment: Yes and no. If the device was previously connected, the router might still have the MAC in a table of addresses it handed out with DHCP. Otherwise, probably not. (Oh, and this question doesn't seem related to programming, so it will probably get more/better answers somewhere else).

Comment: @jerry, I couldn't really determine the site that would be best for this, superuser? serverfault? So I posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is broadcasting, or if it's connected to another access point, then capturing the wifi data would allow you to capture the device's MAC address. Routers aren't generally set up to listen in that way, and I don't think it would be simple to configure that kind of behavior.

In general, if a device isn't connected to a wireless router/access point, you aren't going to be able to capture its MAC.